# Pressing Keys Using Cisco JTapi

Tags: java, cisco, jtapi, cisco-jtapi

I am trying to press keys programmatically using Cisco JTapi. Right now I am able to make calls and receive calls using JTapi. However, I cannot find any relevant information regarding key presses. Could anyone tell me how to do this or point me in the right direction. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know nothing about JTapi, so forgive my ignorance. I learned about a `sendData(byte[] terminalData)` method via the documentation [here](https://developer.cisco.com/site/jtapi/overview/), perhaps it is what you're looking for.

Are you referring to key presses via the softphone?

Comment: Yes. I am referring to key presses via the softphone. I do not think sendData will do the key presses.

Comment: Never mind. SendData was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much. Just had to pass in xml into the senddata. Example if anyone else needs: ciscoterminal.sendData("<CiscoIPPhoneExecute><ExecuteItem URL='Key:Applications'/><ExecuteItem URL='Key:KeyPad0'/></CiscoIPPhoneExecute>");  This presses applications button(settings) and then the button 0.

Comment: Please submit your solution as an answer to this post, it sure could come in handy for others!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to execute key presses on a cisco phone using Jtapi, the sendData command can be used on a CiscoTerminal. Example

```
ciscoterminal.sendData("<CiscoIPPhoneExecute><ExecuteItem URL='Key:Applications'/><ExecuteItem URL='Key:KeyPad0'/></CiscoIPPhoneExecute>");
```

The above example presses the applications button(settings) and then the button 0.
Be sure that the data sent is below 1000 bytes otherwise the request will be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion JTAPI is not made for device control, it is for call control.

I don't know Cisco very much, I'm using Avaya. In the Avaya world there is an API called DMCC which implements CSTA III. I think you should look for a similar API from Cisco.